# URL Rewriting sitemap.xml with Joomla and Xmap

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, joomla, sitemap

I'm using Xmap to create an XML sitemap for my Joomla website. I can access the sitemap by going to index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1

I want to use Apache's URL rewriting to make this available via "sitemap.xml" instead, so I tried using this code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1 [L]
```

However that gives me an error message:

> Error 500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: xml, xml, xmapView

What do I need to do to get this working?

(If it makes a difference, the site is running from a sub-directory, not the root of the domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using add suffix to URL in the Joomla global configuration. If that is the case, please add the following code to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml

RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_xmap&id=1&view=xml&format=html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget the QSA tag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I added QSA but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, another way to accomplish the same result without using Rewrite is to create a sitemap.xml file in the root of your site with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
  <loc>http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_xmap&amp;view=xml&amp;tmpl=component&amp;id=1</loc>
</sitemap>

</sitemapindex>
```

The specifics of what's inside the`<loc> </loc>` line will vary from site to site, grab it from the backend > components > Xmap > XML site map link

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks David, I never knew about sitemap indexes. If anybody's looking for more info, sitemaps.org has details [here](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index).